# Astro MDX page: window.navigator.platform constantly returning null

Tags: astrojs

I have an mdx page that is trying to render differing content based on whether the user is running Windows or Mac. However,determining platform via navigator seems to always return null, and thus present the I'm not sure what platform you're running text when viewing the html.

`

```
---
layout: ../../layouts/toc.astro
title: "document title"
author: "Insert author here"
date: "13 Jul 2023"
---
{() => {
  const getOperatingSystem = (() => {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
       //If the code is not running in the browser (e.g., server-side), return null - we don't want errors
      return null;
    }
        if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) {
      return "Windows";
    } else if (window.navigator.platform.indexOf("Mac") != -1) {
      return "Mac";
    } else {
      return "Unknown";
    }
  })();

  
  <p>Your system should meet or exceed the following minimum requirements</p>
  if (getOperatingSystem === "Windows") {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Windows Requirements:</p>
      </>
    );
  }

  else if (getOperatingSystem=== "Mac") {
    return (
      <>
        <p>Mac Requirements:</p>
      </>
    );
  }

  return ("you are currently running " + getOperatingSystem); // kind of hard to display the system requirements for an unknown platform
}}`
```

Comment: [Astro JSX](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-syntax/#jsx-like-expressions) happens server-side (or at build time). Create an html `script` tag to perform [client-side javascript](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/), or use a [UI framework](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/).